# Mac Mini with Ubuntu running very hot

Tags: 22.04, overheating, mac-mini

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome on a Mac Mini late 2012 with 16GB Ram and a 1TB SSD.

Even when it's doing nothing and the CPU activity is idling at about 10% the case is getting very hot. Much hotter than it used to when I had Mac OS on it.

I have tried both "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Xorg" options when logging in with no noticeable difference.

This issue is not causing me any problems but I am worried that the life of the hardware will be shortened by overheating. I would like to get another 10 years out of this machine, it still gives good performance. (I presume it has a cut-off mechanism in case it gets dangerously hot!)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are your temperature readings for CPU and disks (just to get a reference)? Also, why is the CPU idling at 10% - that sounds like a lot (I would assume 1-2%).

Comment: @Gearóid: Did you have any success on minimizing the idle cpu usage?

Comment: @rubybeginner No, sorry, I abandoned plans to run Ubuntu on this box and went back to Mac OS. I use it as a file server and for VMs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar computer (A1347 mid 2011) that I was running Ubuntu Server on and had a similar problem. Turns out that the CPU heat exchanger that sits between the fan and the outlet slot on the body was full of fluff. The fan was clean and spinning correctly. Going by the specs you posted you've had the thing in bits to do the HDD upgrade. Hope that helps.

[image: Picture of heat exchanger]

Comment: Thank you. It's a useful suggestion. I will check that.

Comment: I checked this and it wasn't the problem. I went back to Mac OS on this box. I use it as a file server and for VMs.